# How to create a loop in sql, is this the best technique here?

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, t-sql

I need a count for all records that contain a specific code. So, a count for `code == 1`, `code == 2`, `code == 3`. I am new to sql and I do not know the most efficient way to insert a technique into this code. The way that feels most intuitive is to say `list_of_codes = [0001, 0002, 00003, 00004]` and create a loop that goes over the array, but I do not think sql works in this manner. Can anyone help me figure out how to write this?

```
 select 
   (SELECT count(columns) as occurences
  FROM database.table
  where code = 00001 /*** where I need to insert a variable name */ 
  and admitdate between '01JAN2016' and '02FEB2016') 
+ (SELECT count(columns2) as occurences
  FROM database2.table2
  where code2 = 00001 /** where I need to insert a variable name */ 
  and startdate between '01JAN2016' and '02FEB2016') sumcount;
```

At the end I want the output to look like:

```
code1: 596 
code2: 39439
code3: 30303
```

Comment: MySQL and tsql are mutually exclusive.

Comment: does it mean that records for each code have to satisfy specific condition, such `admitdate between '01JAN2016' and '02FEB2016'` or  `startdate between '01JAN2016' and '02FEB2016'`?

Comment: @RadimBača yes the records do have to satisfy that specific condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IN` operator

```
 select 
   (SELECT count(columns) as occurences
  FROM database.table
  where code in (1,2,3)
  and admitdate between '20160101' and '20160202') 
+ (SELECT count(columns2) as occurences
  FROM database2.table2
  where code in (1,2,3)
  and startdate between '20160101' and '20160202') sumcount;
```

If you are looking for `count` in each `code` then

```
SELECT a.code,
       a.occurences + b.occurences
FROM   (SELECT code,
               Count(columns) AS occurences
        FROM   database.table
        WHERE  code IN ( 1, 2, 3 )
               AND admitdate BETWEEN '20160101' AND '20160202'
        GROUP  BY code)a
       INNER JOIN (SELECT code,
                          Count(columns2) AS occurences
                   FROM   database2.table2
                   WHERE  code IN ( 1, 2, 3 )
                          AND startdate BETWEEN '20160101' AND '20160202'
                   GROUP  BY code)b
               ON a.code = b.code
```

Comment: this worked thankyou! How does the code)b part of the code work? What does that do?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
l_output NUMBER;

BEGIN

FOR i IN 1..3 LOOP
SELECT count(columns) as occurences into 1_output
FROM database.table
where code in (1,2,3)
and admitdate between '20160101' and '20160202'

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Result: ' || l_output);

END LOOP;

END;
```